# Best way to hide tile edge *and* hardie board edge?

Tags: tile, trim, backsplash

My googlefu may be off, but I cannot find what I'm looking for...  I'm installing a backsplash using 3/8 inch thick marble.  The tile will be set on 1/4 inch backer board (didn't want to demo to the studs, and the wall surface is not suitable).

The total thickness of backer->thinset->tile is about 3/4 inch.  There are a couple of spots where I need to hide the edges of the backer+thinset+tile assembly.  I would like to use a brushed aluminum trim piece to accomplish this, but cannot find anything suitable.  All the Schluter trim pieces seem to be L-shaped which works fine for hiding *only* the tile edge or the backer (depending on which way your orient the L) because they do not appear to make 3/4 inch wide L-shaped trim that I'd need to hide everything.  I suppose what I need is a T-shaped trim with a 1/4 inch hide on one side, and 1/2 inch on the other.  Anyone know a source for such a thing?

I'm toying with the idea of just using the trim that is available to hide just the backer board.  Then maybe just use white caulk along the sides of the tile to hide the thinset layer...  Anyone ever do that and how does it look?  Would it be difficult to achieve something decent looking?

(Please note: bullnose for this particular tile is not available and I don't want to fabricate my own.  Also, we don't care for the look of quarter round finish.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for "Reno-T"  Schluter.
[image: Reno-T]

However, you might want to consider looking for 'bull-nosed' versions of your current tile:

[image: Bull Nose Tile]

or matching some v-cap, deco mold, granada shaped 'chair rail' as trim:

[image: Chair Rail types]